# Получение цвета на View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Ребята всем привет.
По умолчанию стоит цвет 'initialColor': '#8e44ad'. А Можно как нибудь сделать что если в базе уже есть цвет @Model.Color !="" тогда он береться от туда иначе по умолчанию ставиться '#8e44ad'
View

```js
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUploadedFiles", "TrainingType", FormMethod.Post, new
    { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @*pic*@
    
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" 
                    name="Picker1">
                    <div class="picker" id="picker1"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="colorType" name="color" value="#8E44AD" />
                    @*pic*@
    
                    <script>
                        $("#picker1").colorPick({
                            'initialColor': '#8e44ad',
                            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                            'onColorSelected': function () {
                                console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                                this.element.css({ 'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color });
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Js

```js
$("#picker1").colorPick({
  'initialColor': '#8e44ad',
  'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
  'onColorSelected': function() {
    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
    this.element.css({
      'backgroundColor': this.color,
      'color': this.color
    });
  }
});
```

Пробовал сделать так

```js
var initialColor = @Model.Color;
$("#picker1").colorPick({
  get initialColor() {
    return initialColor;
  },
  set initialColor(value) {
    initialColor = value;
  },
  'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
  'onColorSelected': function() {
    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
    this.element.css({
      'backgroundColor': this.color,
      'color': this.color
    });
  }
});
```

Не работает. Кто нибудь моэет пожалуйста подсказать путь для решения?

Comment: заполняйте в конструкторе свою модель model.Color дефолтным значением, если из базы вернулось пустое значение

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий но проблема немного в другом.  Обратите внимания пожалуйста на JS. `initialColor': '#8e44ad'` вот это значение. Я бы в него хотел выставлять значение которое уже есть в базе. `initialColor': @Model.Color` - не работат

Comment: @Boris костыль вставьте в виде какого-нибудь пустого скрытого элемента, например div.. из жса уже берите значение. Т.е всё будет так: C# задает атрибут  `<div color=@Model.Color hidden>`, в жс получаете `color` из этого `div`.

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо так сделал, работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ дал Aarnihauta смотрите комментарии